# Help Simplifying Expressions

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I have the following set of equations:

**1)**

$\text{$b_1$} \cos (\text{$\beta_1$} u)-\text{$b_1$} \cosh (\text{$\beta_1$} u)-\text{$b2$} \cos (\text{$\beta_1$} \theta  y)-\text{$d_2$} \cosh (\text{$\beta_1$} \theta  y)\sin (\text{$\beta_1$} u)-\sinh (\text{$\beta_1$} u)=0$

**2)**

$-\text{$b_1$} \sin (\text{$\beta_1$} u)-\text{$b_1$} \sinh (\text{$\beta_1$} u)+\text{$b_2$} \theta  \sin (\text{$\beta $1} \theta  y)-\text{$d_2$} \theta  \sinh (\text{$\beta_1$} \theta  y)+\cos (\text{$\beta_1$} u)-\cosh (\text{$\beta_1$} u)=0$

**3)**

$-\text{$b_1$} \cos (\text{$\beta_1$} u)-\text{$b_1$} \cosh (\text{$\beta_1$} u)+\alpha ^4 \text{$b_2$} \theta ^2 \cos (\text{$\beta_1$} \theta  y)-\alpha ^4 \text{$d_2$} \theta ^2 \cosh (\text{$\beta_1$} \theta  y)-\sin (\text{$\beta_1$} u)-\sinh (\text{$\beta_1$} u)=0$

... and I would like to find the constants $b_1$, $b_2$ and $d_2$.

I already know the answers:

$b_1 =\frac{\sin \left(\beta _1 u\right)-\sinh \left(\beta _1 u\right)}{\cosh \left(\beta _1 u\right)-\cos \left(\beta _1
   u\right)}$

$b_2 =\frac{2 \cos \left(\beta _1 u\right) \left(\cos \left(\beta _1 u\right) \cosh \left(\beta _1
   u\right)-1\right)}{\theta  \left(\cosh \left(\beta _1 u\right)-\cos \left(\beta _1 u\right)\right) \left(\cos
   \left(\beta _1 \theta  y\right) \sinh \left(\beta _1 \theta  y\right)+\sin \left(\beta _1 \theta  y\right) \cosh
   \left(\beta _1 \theta  y\right)\right)}$

$d_2 = -b_2 \frac{\cos \left(\beta _1 \theta  y\right)}{\cosh \left(\beta _1 \theta  y\right)}$

... but I want to prove it with Mathematica:

```
eq={b1 Cos[u β1] - b2 Cos[y β1 θ] - 
      b1 Cosh[u β1] - d2 Cosh[y β1 θ] + 
      Sin[u β1] - Sinh[u β1], 
     Cos[u β1] - Cosh[u β1] - b1 Sin[u β1] + 
      b2 θ Sin[y β1 θ] - b1 Sinh[u β1] - 
      d2 θ Sinh[y β1 θ], -b1 Cos[u β1] + 
      b2 α^4 θ^2 Cos[y β1 θ] - 
      b1 Cosh[u β1] - 
      d2 α^4 θ^2 Cosh[y β1 θ] - 
      Sin[u β1] - Sinh[u β1]}
```

I want to find the constants `{b1, b2, d2}`

```
Solve[# == 0 & /@ eq, {b1, b2, d2}] // Simplify
```

... **The results are large terms and I have trouble simplifying it. Any help would be highly appreciated !**

Comment: I would verify that the equations and solutions are consistent by substituting numerical values for all variables.

Comment: Since you believe you know the value of b1,b2,d2 then `FullSimplify[expr1==0,{b1=..,b2=.., d2=..}]` should have pretty good chances of returning `True`, but it returns `b2 Cos[y β1 θ] + (1 + d2 Cosh[y β1 θ]) Sin[u β1] == 0` which tends to make me think there might be a typo or another error. If I try to do the substitutions for b1,b2,d2 the result is even worse. Are you certain no errors slipped through? I tried to carefully undo all your Latex work to get it back into MMA, but I might have made mistakes doing that too.

Comment: Because `α` does not appear in the solution given, it follows that `b2 Cos[y β1 θ] - d2 Cosh[y β1 θ] == 0`, which clearly is inconsistent with the solution for `d2` in the question.  I believe that there are errors in `eq`.

Comment: @Bill Thank you very much for your comment and your help ! Indeed this might be a mistake on my side. I will check everything again... but this might take a while.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for your comment. Yes, there is an error somewhere. As I have already told Bill, I will check everything again. However, this might take a while...

Comment: @mikado This is a great idea !

Comment: If you are confident that your answers are correct, finding the correct equations should not be too difficult.

Comment: I apologize for an error. I should have written `FullSimplify[expr1==0,{b1==.., b2==.., d2==..}]` instead and didn't want you wasting time because of my error.

Comment: @Bill It's completly fine !  Thanks for noting your error.